# Error resolving template, template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the following controller:

```
@Controller
public class ConfigController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "config";
    }
}
```

However, I receive the following error when going to the route `/`:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template [config], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [config], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

I have a `config.html` file inside of `resources/templates`:

[image]

My pom.xml file: https://pastebin.com/yqYYuXWh

What am I doing wrong?

I have already tried adding a `.html` to the return of the controller function, but it still doesn't work.

---

After removing the spring-web dependency (I already had `spring-boot-starter-web`) I now get the following error when starting spring:

`Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)`

Comment: You need to remove `spring-web` from your pom.xml. Also it seems like you added a lot of different sql connectors, normally you'd only need one.

Comment: @IdanElhalwani Sadly this application will be distributed and needs to connect to pretty much every DB there is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in your pom.xml file.

By adding this block to your `build`;

```xml
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>application.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

You have overriden `spring-boot-starter-parent`'s own `resources` block and caused it to include `application.properties` and nothing else. Remove it from your pom.xml and delete your target directory.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fix if someone has met all the requirements.Check the return value of the method. if you something like `return '/admin/index'` change it to `return 'admin/index`

Answer (score 1):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.20</version>
    </dependency>
```

The second dependency is not required.

```xml
    <build>
<!--not required. Spring boot scans /resources directory by default 
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>application.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
-->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Please rebuild and restart the app again.

And you don't need to add `.html` extension in your controller. Spring boot looks for `.html`,`.jsp` extensions in `src/main/resource/` ,`src/main/resource/templates/` ,`src/main/resource/static/` ,`src/main/resource/public` these directories by default

Comment: I have removed the second dependency and now the following error appears when starting spring: `Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using in developing Spring Boot appl'. To me below method works. That is change "**" set for 'Excluded' to (none).

[image]

Comment: Could you specify which version of Eclipse you are using? I started getting this behaviour after switching from 2022-12 to 2023-12.

Comment: That is, Eclipse(Spring Tool Suite 4 flavor, Version: 4.21.0.RELEASE)

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your handler method with **@ResponseBody** annotation like this
**public @ResponseBody String index()**
The @ResponseBody annotation tells a controller that the object returned is automatically serialized into JSON and passed back into the HttpResponse object. When you use the @ResponseBody annotation on a method, Spring converts the return value and writes it to the HTTP response automatically.