# Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

index.html works perfectly but if I click a link in it, eclipse gives me these errors and the site goes error 404.

logs:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
   at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
   at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.15.RELEASE.jar:3.0.15.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1401) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1145) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1084) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:403) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:249) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]

2022-05-27 17:33:12.749 ERROR 668 --- [nio-9090-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
```

my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
   <link href="/frontpage.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <title>Catering Ristorazione C.S.L</title>
   </head>
<body>
   <div>
       <h1> <strong><em>Catering Ristorazione C.S.L</em></strong></h1>
       <div> <hr>
       <a th:href="@{/elencochefs}" >Elenco degli chef</a>
       </div>
       <div> 
       <a th:href="@{/elencobuffets}" >Elenco dei buffet</a> 
       </div>
        </hr> 
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

the page i try to get redirected to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
   <title>Chefs</title>
   <link href="/elencochefs.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
   <h3>I nostri Chefs:</h3>
   <ul>
   <li th:each="chef : ${chefs}">
       <a  href="chef.html" class= "link"
            th:href="@{'/chef' + '/' + '/${chef.id}}"
            th:text="${chef.nome} + ' ' + ${chef.cognome}">Paolo Rossi</a>
   </li>
   </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

thymeleaf configuration:

```
# = Thymeleaf configurations
#==================================
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.servlet.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
```

[image]

I honestly dont know where the problem could be, so I dont know what part of my code you need...ask and i'll post it, thank you for your time and help

EDIT:

my controller class:

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import com.example.demo.model.Chef;
import com.example.demo.service.ChefService;
import com.example.demo.validator.ChefValidator;

@Controller
public class ChefController {

    @Autowired
    private ChefService cs;
    @Autowired
    private ChefValidator cv;


    //funzione per aggiungere uno chef
    @PostMapping("/chef")
    public String addChef(@Valid @ModelAttribute("chef") Chef chef, Model model, BindingResult bindingresult) {
        this.cv.validate(chef, bindingresult);
        if(!bindingresult.hasErrors()) {
            this.cs.save(chef);
            model.addAttribute("chef", cs.findById(chef.getId()));
            return "chef.html";
        }
        else
            return "chefForm.html";
    }

    //funzione per rimuovere uno chef
    @DeleteMapping("/deleteChef/{id}")
    public String removeChef(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {

        cs.deleteById(id);
        model.addAttribute("chefs", cs.findAll());
        return "elencochefs.html";
    }


    //elenco degli chef
    @GetMapping("/chefs")
    public String getChefs(Model model) {

        List<Chef> chefs = cs.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("chefs", chefs);
        return "elencochefs.html";
    }

    //uno chef in particolare
    @GetMapping("/chef/{id}")
    public String getChef(@PathVariable("id")Long id, Model model) {

        Chef chef = cs.findById(id);
        model.addAttribute("chef",chef);
        return "chef.html";
    }

    //form per aggiungere chef  
    @GetMapping("/chefForm")
    public String getChef(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("chef", new Chef());
        return "chefForm.html";
    }


    //form per rimuovere chef
    @GetMapping("/chefToDelete/{id}")
    public String deleteChef(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("cheftoDelete", cs.findById(id));
        return "chefToDelete.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can research similar questions (and update your own question with any findings), to at least rule out some possible suggestions. For example, this was asked earlier today: [Error resolving template, template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72406562/12567365). And I expect there are various similar questions, also.

Comment: In your case, if you don't have an `error.html` template, then what if you create it? Maybe that will allow a more relevant error message to be generated.

Comment: Add code of the controller method which is called from that link

Comment: I added the controller class

Comment: @andrewJames all similar questions I found were about actual templates they had, my error suggest an [error] template and I dont know why

Comment: You're seeing an error when trying to display an error page, but that is not the root problem. The root problem is what triggered the error in the first place. See if there are different errors higher up in your logs.

Comment: See my 2nd comment. Does that help expose the root cause problem?

Comment: @andrewJames if I create an error.html file, when I click on a link in index.html it will redirect me to error.html page. No errors, but wrong page

Comment: @knox That is the first error i get, no other errors higher up

Comment: Where is the controller with mappings for `/elencochefs` or `/elencobuffets`?  What is your browser url when you click a link from  your index.html.?

Comment: @Metroids Ok that was the problem...I didnt know I had to use the same name for the mapping, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

You have to register "/elencochefs & /elencobuffets" these both endpoints in your controller & also additionally you can add/write error.html file to auto redirect for any error in application.

Failure Reason:
In your index.html,

```
<a th:href="@{/elencochefs}" >Elenco degli chef</a> 
<a th:href="@{/elencobuffets}" >Elenco dei buffet</a>
```

these both links/endpoints (/elencochefs & /elencobuffets) are not configured/mapped in your controller.

Hence when you click on them, your application will not find them & will return with 404. But to display that 404 error with mesage on UI, it finds error.html, which is not configured/written by you.

So it will give you another error in logs saying "org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [error], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers".